# Changing the button attribute once button is clicked in JSON Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON Datatables that has array objects and a button to send data. So once the button has been clicked, the button should turn grey into "btn-default". The problem is im doing it in separate ajax calls as follows,

```
$.getJSON('invoice/source/process/po_list_table.php', {vendId: vendId, jobId: jobId}, function (response) {

            // Initializes Button to Send to invoice list
            $.each(response, function() {
                this.sendButton = "<button class='btn btn-success btn-outline btn-xs' id='addToInvoice'>ADD</button>";
            });

            // Initialize DataTables for Listing PO
            var poTable = $('#listPoByJobTable').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                ordering: false,
                info: false,
                bFilter: false,
                processing: true,
                scrollY: "500px",
                scrollCollapse: true,
                data: response,
                destroy: true,
                oLanguage: {
                    "sSearch": ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: "PO_NO"},
                    {data: "sendButton"}
                ]
            });

            // Button function
            $('#listPoByJobTable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
                var data = poTable.row( $(this).parents('tr')).data();
                alert(data["PO_NO"]);
            });

            // Initialize AJAX onClick Data Send
            window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
        });
```

So when the button is clicked,  `this.sendButton = "<button class='btn btn-success btn-outline btn-xs' id='addToInvoice'>ADD</button>` should turn into `class='btn btn-default btn-outline btn-xs`.

Please help me since i am kind of confused on how to do this. Thanks